# Why won't the Vault 81 gear-shaped door open?

Tags: fallout-4

When I walk into the cave containing Vault 81, after I pass the persuasion check, the main vault door (I'm not talking about the one after you finish talking face-to-face with the Overseer, I'm talking about the actual main vault door shaped like a gear with 81 written in the center) won't open. The warning lights around the door start strobing, but the door never opens.

I'm playing on a PS4 and therefore (as far as I know) don't have access to console commands.

Comment: There is a bug note on the Wiki page for this vault: "After using the speech check, the main door never opens. Reloading to an earlier save (before the speech check) can fix this."  Have you tried this?

Comment: Yes, and it didn't work.

Comment: @BeachCutler you can unlock whole map with console command. then fast travel to vault 88. you will land inside vault.

Comment: 1. I'm talking about Vault 81, not 88.I happen to be playing Fo4 on a PS4, therefore I have no console. Are there any fixes specific to PS4 users?

Comment: Have you tried this? https://fallout.fandom.com/wiki/Vault_81#Bugs

Comment: I just did, and I tried all of them, and none of them worked.

Comment: What about old-school Power Armor glitch? (Stand backwards to doors closer as possible and exit PA.. ) maybe it will be to far and you ends in matrix, maybe it ,, spawn ,, you in